# pdf Form Fields password protect asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I'm using this tutorial https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030211-1.aspx that’s uses a PDF Form Fields, lets the user input fields using textbox's. I would like to encrypt the pdf and add a user password so when its download they will need the password to open the pdf.

```
   public static byte[] GeneratePDF(string pdfPath, Dictionary<string, string> formFieldMap)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath); 
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

    var formFields = stamper.AcroFields;

    foreach (var fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
        formFields.SetField(fieldName, formFieldMap[fieldName]);

    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();

    byte[] content = output.ToArray();
//    byte[] content = content;

    // Write out PDF from memory stream.

    return output.ToArray();

}
```

Comment: can you be more descriptive in your question? add at least one use case of what you mean with **I would like to add a password to the pdf.**

Comment: Sorry I would like to encrypt the pdf and add a user password so when its download they will need the password to open the pdf

Comment: is a password per file or do you have in mind to put an authentication /authorization system?

Comment: per file and send the password via e-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me try to change the logistics of how the application it's going to behave, instead of sending a password every time that a user should download a pdf try to put in place a proper authentication and authorization system.

just look at this case:

- the user get a list of pdf files
- when the user click over a download button they get redirected to a login page
- they enter their credentials get redirected to the file list
- they click over the pdf and download it
- if they don't have any permissions to download it the link will appear disable
- the admin can add permissions to download files to a different users

  hope that helps